# In servlet based application HttpSession is having the session Id while HttpServlet requestArg, requestArg.getRequestedSessionId() is returning null

Tags: session, servlets

In my application, when I hit the submit button on the login screen, one Login.do action is performed. Inside that action when the credentials are successfully authenticated, a new HttpSession localSession is created using

```
public ActionForward executeAction(ActionMapping mappingArg,
        ActionForm formArg, HttpServletRequest requestArg,
        HttpServletResponse responseArg, Connection connectionArg)
        throws Exception{
           ********login credentials authentication code*******
           HttpServletRequest localHttpRequest = requestArg;
           HttpSession session = localHttpRequest.getSession(true);

}
```

after this the request is forwarded to the RequestProcessor where I am trying to validate the session using

```
public void process(HttpServletRequest requestArg,
        HttpServletResponse responseArg) throws ServletException, IOException
{
                        System.out.println("Request Arg Session Id:" +                  requestArg.getRequestedSessionId());
            System.out.println("RequestArg Session:" + requestArg.getSession());
            System.out.println("RequestArg cookie:"+ requestArg.getCookies());
            System.out.println("RequestArg class:"+ requestArg.getClass());
            HttpSession localSession = requestArg.getSession(false);
            System.out.println("Http sessionID:" + localSession.getId());
            if(!requestArg.isRequestedSessionIdValid()){
                           ***display error***
                        }
}
```

and below is what I am getting in the console

> Request Arg Session Id:null
>
> Request Arg Session:org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@dfdd572
>
> RequestArg cookie:null RequestArg class:class
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
>
> HttpsessionID:F71********************3B1

Also, I noticed one thing. In the executeAction() Method the requestArg is of type and **org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade** while in the process() method the requestArg is coming of type **org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest**. Why is this happening?

After the session is generated when the login credentials are verified, the program goes to the process() method where the error is popping. I was expecting the session to do not come null in the console and carry on with the normal flow.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. Do you expect a http session? You should make a request. Why it's happening? Because you use Tomcat as an application server. Clarify your specific problem. The way you are written it out is not answerable.

Comment: *"after this the request is forwarded"* send a redirect instead.